# No method error when calling a helper method from its controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Should this work?

```
module SessionsHelper
    def foobar
        "hello"
    end
end

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        foobar
    end
end
```

When I visit the URI that goes to `session#new` I get an `undefined method or variable 'foobar'` error. I thought helper modules were automatically included in their respective controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Well, including the module from the controller did it:

```
module SessionsHelper
    def foobar
        "hello"
    end
end

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    include SessionsHelper

    def new
        foobar
    end
end
```

I thought this behaviour was default in rails though? That the relevant helper modules are included in their controllers?

Comment: By default helpers are included in views. If You want to use them in controllers, You must include a module.

Comment: Ah fair enough, that does explain it :P ...I thought modules were for abstracted controller logic, drapers for abstracted view logic..